# Optimize Advance SQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

**Info of Tables**
[image]
I have the following tables with their pupose:

*student* table: stores basic info of students

*fee_received* table: stores info of Monthly Tution Fees paid by each student for each month in a year.

**Problem:**
I need to get all the students who are fee_defaulters in any of the last 7 months of 2018. Most importantly I need all those months (e.g: 3, 4, 6) for each student so that I can show it to the admin that which student is fee defaulter in which months.

**Tables Schema**

```
 CREATE TABLE `fee_received` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `challan_no` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `student_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `class_id` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `amount` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `arrears` int(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'arrears in monthly tuition fee.',
  `fine` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'total fine in current challan',
  `fee_month` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `fee_year` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `dt` date NOT NULL,
  `multi_fee` tinyint(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `submitted_with_admission` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT '1 = received , 2 = pending, 3 = deleted'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `student` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `reg_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `f_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `cnic1` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cnic` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `caste` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `occupation` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dob` date NOT NULL,
  `gender` enum('M','F','O','') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'M',
  `contact` varchar(13) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `admission_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**Current unoptimized working Solution:**
*Note: I have very much simplified the solution for StackOverflow just to show the problem area*

The following sub_query gets all the students who have paid fee of all the 7  months.

```
$already_paid_student_ids_query = "SELECT t.student_id
    FROM (
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS count, student_id
        FROM fee_received
        WHERE fee_month IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
        AND fee_year = 2018
        AND class_id = 10
        AND status = 1
        GROUP BY student_id
    ) AS t
    WHERE t.count >= 7";
```

Then I have the following main query which is giving me all students who are fee defaulters.

```
$fee_defaulters_query = "SELECT student.* FROM student
    WHERE student.id NOT IN ( {$already_paid_student_ids_query} )";
```

Till this point I have got all the fee defaulters. But I don't know that which student is fee defaulter in which month. So for that, I have applied a very costly solution.

I have looped through each fee defaulter and requesting the fee_received table to get months for the student.

```
$paid_months_query = "SELECT fee_month FROM fee_received WHERE student_id = {$student_id} AND fee_year = {$fee_year} AND fee_month IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) AND status = 1 ";
```

Then using some programing I get the unpaid months for each student and display to the admin.

**Required Solution**

I need to get rid of the query inside loop. And need a solution so that I get all the fee_defaulter students and list of unpaid months for each students in a single query.

**SQL Fiddle Link**
[link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ea0af1e)

Comment: You just need to modify your second query and add an order by clause on the dates. You could use the MONTH() function to order them by months. Also add a to your where clause a BETWEEN clause to select the period you want.

Comment: Edit your question and show the schema of each table (not just a list of column names).

Comment: The sub-query on your first statement isn't needed. It can be done using JOIN in your 2nd query.

Comment: You should never store dates in separate columns. Store as TIMESTAMP or DATETIME. There are simple functions to get the month and year, and for this case, you could write a query that would always return the last X months, or between any two dates or even year to date.

Comment: Currently I can use joins and the solution you people have suggested but that way I will get duplicate records. For example if a student has paid fee of 4 months I will get 4 records for that student. And then I will have to exclude the duplicates using programming.

Comment: I need a query which gives me single record for each fee_defaulter
e.g.:

Sloan Thrasher     4,5,7

Here this student has paid fee of only these 3 months, so I can get the unpaid months by excluding these months programmatically.

Comment: If you put your schema (the create table text) in as text, then I can create a SQL Fiddle to provide a query that won't duplicate rows. But remember that we are volunteers and you are asking for free help, so make it easy for us to answer. Don't post images of your schema. I'm not going to type your table schemas from an image.

Comment: @SloanThrasher I have updated the question and you can see the schema now. Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry let me create a fiddle and post the link to it here.

Comment: here is the [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ea0af1e) to sql fiddle [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ea0af1e)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a SQL Fiddle that produces a list of students with missing payments. It also shows which months they have made payments.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dd0945/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE `fee_received` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `challan_no` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `student_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `class_id` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `amount` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `arrears` int(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'arrears in monthly tuition fee.',
  `fine` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'total fine in current challan',
  `fee_month` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `fee_year` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `dt` date NOT NULL,
  `multi_fee` tinyint(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `submitted_with_admission` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT '1 = received , 2 = pending, 3 = deleted'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `student` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `reg_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `f_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `cnic1` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cnic` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `caste` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `occupation` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dob` date NOT NULL,
  `gender` enum('M','F','O','') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'M',
  `contact` varchar(13) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `admission_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `student`
(`reg_no`, `name`, `f_name`, `cnic1`, `cnic`, `caste`, `occupation`, `dob`, `gender`, `contact`, `address`, `admission_id`)
VALUES
(1123,'John Doe','John','1','1','1','student','2000-05-01','M','123-456-7890','123 S Western Ave',123),
(1533,'Jane Doe','Jane','1','1','1','student','2000-05-01','F','123-456-7890','123 S Western Ave',123),
(2341,'Fred Smith','Fred','1','1','1','student','2000-05-01','M','123-456-7890','123 S Western Ave',123),
(6541,'Tanya Edilstien','Tanya','1','1','1','student','2000-05-01','M','123-456-7890','123 S Western Ave',123);

INSERT INTO `fee_received`
(`challan_no`, `student_id`, `class_id`, `amount`, `arrears`, `fine`, `fee_month`, `fee_year`, `dt`, `multi_fee`, `submitted_with_admission`, `status`)
VALUES
(1,1,1,123,0,0,1,2018,'2018-01-04',0,0,1),
(1,1,1,123,0,0,2,2018,'2018-02-04',0,0,1),
(1,1,1,123,0,0,3,2018,'2018-03-04',0,0,1),
(1,1,1,123,0,0,4,2018,'2018-04-04',0,0,1),
(1,1,1,123,0,0,5,2018,'2018-05-04',0,0,1),
(1,1,1,123,0,0,6,2018,'2018-06-04',0,0,1),
(1,1,1,123,0,0,7,2018,'2018-07-04',0,0,1),
(2,2,2,123,0,0,1,2018,'2018-01-04',0,0,1),
(2,2,2,123,0,0,4,2018,'2018-04-04',0,0,1),
(2,2,2,123,0,0,5,2018,'2018-05-04',0,0,1),
(2,2,2,123,0,0,6,2018,'2018-06-04',0,0,1),
(2,2,2,123,0,0,7,2018,'2018-07-04',0,0,1),
(3,3,3,123,0,0,1,2018,'2018-01-04',0,0,1),
(3,3,3,123,0,0,2,2018,'2018-02-04',0,0,1),
(3,3,3,123,0,0,3,2018,'2018-03-04',0,0,1),
(3,3,3,123,0,0,4,2018,'2018-04-04',0,0,1),
(3,3,3,123,0,0,5,2018,'2018-05-04',0,0,1),
(3,3,3,123,0,0,7,2018,'2018-07-04',0,0,1),
(4,4,4,123,0,0,1,2018,'2018-01-04',0,0,1),
(4,4,4,123,0,0,2,2018,'2018-02-04',0,0,1),
(4,4,4,123,0,0,3,2018,'2018-03-04',0,0,1),
(4,4,4,123,0,0,4,2018,'2018-04-04',0,0,1),
(4,4,4,123,0,0,5,2018,'2018-05-04',0,0,1),
(4,4,4,123,0,0,6,2018,'2018-06-04',0,0,1),
(4,4,4,123,0,0,7,2018,'2018-07-04',0,0,1);
```

**Query 1**:

```
select 
  a.`id`,
  a.`name`,
  a.`contact`,
  a.`address`,
  count(b.`id`) as `num_payments`,
  GROUP_CONCAT(b.`fee_month` ORDER BY b.`fee_month`) as `Months_Paid`
FROM `student` a
LEFT JOIN `fee_received` b
  ON a.`id` = b.`student_id` AND b.`status` = 1 AND b.`dt` BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-07-31'
GROUP BY a.`id`
HAVING `num_payments` < 7
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dd0945/1/0)**:

```
| id |       name |      contact |           address | num_payments | Months_Paid |
|----|------------|--------------|-------------------|--------------|-------------|
|  2 |   Jane Doe | 123-456-7890 | 123 S Western Ave |            5 |   1,4,5,6,7 |
|  3 | Fred Smith | 123-456-7890 | 123 S Western Ave |            6 | 1,2,3,4,5,7 |
```

Answer (score 1):

For each student you expect payments for certain months. So combine all months with all students. Then see where payments are missing.

```
select student.id as student_id, months.year, months.month
from
(
  select 2018 as year, 1 as month
  union all
  select 2018 as year, 2 as month
  union all
  select 2018 as year, 3 as month
  union all
  select 2018 as year, 4 as month
  union all
  select 2018 as year, 5 as month
  union all
  select 2018 as year, 6 as month
  union all
  select 2018 as year, 7 as month
) months
cross join student
where (student.id, months.year, months.month) not in
(
  select student_id, fee_year, fee_month
  from fee_received
  where class_id = 10
    and status = 1
)
order by student_id, months.year, months.month;
```

(I just copied the class_id condition from your query. If this is a certain class which not all students attend, then you may want to limit students somehow - probably with some student_class table you haven't mentioned.)

If you want one row per student, then you must aggregate:

```
select
  student.id as student_id,
  group_concat(concat(months.year, '/', months.month)) as unpaid_months
from
(
  select 2018 as year, 1 as month
  union all
  select 2018 as year, 2 as month
  union all
  select 2018 as year, 3 as month
  union all
  select 2018 as year, 4 as month
  union all
  select 2018 as year, 5 as month
  union all
  select 2018 as year, 6 as month
  union all
  select 2018 as year, 7 as month
) months
cross join student
where (student.id, months.year, months.month) not in
(
  select student_id, fee_year, fee_month
  from fee_received
  where class_id = 10
    and status = 1
)
group by student.id
order by student.id;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Seems interesting. Let me Just apply your solution. I will get back to you. Yeah there are 69 tables. I have just simplified the question here.

Comment: There was a typo in my second query. It's `concat` of course, not `concate`.